# How could I show methods depending of the generic entity of a class?

Tags: c#

I want to create methods that only will able to use if the generic type of a class is from a specific type.

For example, I have two abstract classes `NamedEntity` and `KeyedEntity` and I have a class which works with a generic type: `MyClass<T>`

I would like to create a method `X` on `MyClass<T>` which only will be able if the `T` is a `NamedEntity` and a method `Y` on `MyClass<T>` which only will be able if `T` is a `KeyedEntity`. If `T` is both, both methods will be shown.

I don't want to implement the method independently of the generic type and thrown an error if the type is not the correct type to use the method, but if this is the only way I will do.

If I could inherit from multiple classes it would be easy, but how `C#`only allow me to inherit from one class it is being hard to think about for me.

**EDIT**

I agree with all your points. I will try to explain better: 
I have an abstract service class, which could work with all the database entities of my system.

All entities could have the "default" methods like "GetById(long id); Create(T entity); Update(T entity)" and it's possible because I am working with an ORM (Nhibernate).

I would like to create the method "GetByName" but not all of the entities have the property "Name", so it will be better if the method GetByName appears only for services which works with a Generic Type that force the entity to have the property "Name", this Generic Type should be the entity class, if I use interfaces (`INamedEntity`, `IKeyedEntity`) the problem continue being the same.

Comment: Not possible. A class is a class. Just because it's a generic class, doesn't mean it can have a separate implementation.

Comment: You can implement logic for handling both `NamedEntity` and `KeyedEntity` in the base abstract class. Mark the methods as [`protected`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) - they will be accessible only inside derived classes. You can then implement `MyClassOfNamedEntity` and `MyClassOfKeyedEntity`, which will both inherit from the same base class. You can implement appropriate public methods, which will in turn call the methods implemented in the base class.

Comment: @Nahum interfaces doesn't help me because I will need to implement the method a lot of times (because interface doesn't have the implementation of the method)

Comment: @Serge I have already thought about it. But the problem is that I will need to create a "MyClassOfNamedAndKeyedEntity` and if I create another type of entity I will need to create classes for all the possibilities.

Comment: This smells aweful...Don't use generics for this, the correct tool is overloading.

Comment: @InBetween Not really, it could helps a lot because I will know what `MyClass` instance  have the possibility to use `X` or `Y` at development time, and not only on execution time.

Comment: @OnlyaCuriousMind And what happens when they are both? You have an ambigous call in your class.

Comment: @InBetween If `T` are both, both methods (`Y`and `X`) will be able to use at `MyClass<T>`

Comment: Then you will need to implement run-time checking and throw a `NotImplementedException()` when required (or some other type of exception).

Comment: You are misunderstanding how generics work. You are basically asking for conditional compilation based upon the type of the generic parameter. It doesn't work that way. Any method using `T` will be compiled and available. If you constraint `T` to somehting in a method inside `MyClass<T>` then `T` will need to have the same constraint at class definition level. There is no way around it.

Comment: So use composition insteaf of inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you are trying to achieve something like the following (non compilable code follows):

```
 class MyClass<T>
 {
      public void X(T t) where T: NamedEntity { ... }
      public void X(T t) where T: KeyedEntitiy { ... }
 }
```

This won't compile You can not constrain `T` at method level, only at class level.

Ok. Constraining at top level seems useless, because you'd need to constrain to both `NamedEntity` and `KeyedEntity` which is self defeating, so let's constrain at method level:

```
class MyClass<T>
{
    public void X<Q>(Q q) where Q: NamedEntity { ... }
    public void X<Q>(Q q) where Q: KeyedEntitiy { ... }
}
```

Now this won't compile because constraints on generic type parameters are not part of a method's signature. The two methods `X` would essentially be the same overload and therefore the compiler will flag the second method with an error; *method X already exists...*.

Also, you'd need to check that `Q` and `T` are actually compatible and this will only be possible at runtime, not at compile time...yuck!

Ok, then the only option seems to be overloading:

```
 public X(NamedEntity entity) { ... }
 public X(KeyedEntity entity) { ... }
```

Of course this is also far from safe at compile time; you still need to check that the right method is called for the actual type of `T` and this check can only be done at runtime. Yuck again...

Also, what happens if you have the following:

```
class Foo: NamedEntity, KeyedEntity { }
myClass.X(new foo()); //now what? What X is called?
```

This whole setup just seems completely off, you should rethink you approach or give more information on what exactly is it you are trying to achieve.

*UPDATE* Ok, all clearer now. The methods dont share the same name, thats a big difference!

Based on new info in your question, I would recommend the following approach:

```
public interface IKeyedIdentity
{
     long Id { get; }
}

public interface INamedIdentity: IKeyedIdentity
{
     string Name { get; }
}

public class MyClass<T> where T: IKeyedIdentity
{
     public void Create(T entity) { ... }
     public void Update(T entity) { ... }
     public T GetById(long id) { ... }

     public Q GetByName<Q>(string name)
         where Q : T, INamedEntity
     { ... } 
}
```

Here it makes sense to make the method generic itself because there is a relationship between `T` and `Q` you can leverage. This wasn't altogether clear before.

Downside, you have to explicitly supply `Q` in calls to `GetName`, I can't think of any compile time safe set up that would avoid this.

*UPDATE #2*: I think you have to take a step back and implement specialized `MyClass<T>`s that know how to deal with each expected entity type.

Consider the following code, it should give you enough ideas to implement a similar pattern in your particular scenario:

```
public static class EntityManagerProvider
{
    public static EntityManager<Q> GetManager<Q>()
    {
        if (typeof(INamedIdentity).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Q)))
            return typeof(NamedEntityManager<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Q)).GetConstructor(new Type[] { }).Invoke(new Type[] { }) as MyClass<Q>;

        if (typeof(IKeyedIdentity).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Q)))
            return typeof(KeyedEntityManager<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Q)).GetConstructor(new Type[] { }).Invoke(new Type[] { }) as MyClass<Q>;

        return null;
    }

    public abstract class EntityManager<T>
    {
        public void Create(T entity) { ... }
        public void Update(T entity) { ... }
        public abstract T GetById(long id);
        public abstract T GetByName(string name);
    }

    private class KeyedEntityManager<Q> : EntityManager<Q> where Q : IKeyedIdentity
    {
        public override Q GetById(long id) { return default(Q); }
        public override Q GetByName(string name) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    }

    private class NamedEntityManager<Q> : EntityManager<Q> where Q : INamedIdentity
    {
        public override Q GetById(long id) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
        public override Q GetByName(string name) { return default(Q); }
    }
}
```

Now you can do the following:

```
var myNamedFooManager = MyClassProvider.GetMyClass<NamedFoo>();
var namedFoo = myNamedFooManager.GetByName("Foo"); //I know this call is safe.
var myKeyedFooManager = MyClassProvider.GetMyClass<KeyedFoo>();
var keyedFoo = myNamedFooManager.GetById(0); //I know this call is safe.
```

Downside: if you need to interact with a given entity that is both keyed and named in either way, you'll have to use two distinct managers.

Comment: Thank you by your answer, I agree with all your points, I edited my question with more info.

Comment: @OnlyaCuriousMind Updated answer. Check if proposed approach works for you.

Comment: Yes I have thought about this solution, but there is a problem: Not all of my NamedEntity are KeyedEntity and vice versa. So I would need to create a interface named "INamedAndKeyedEntity", BUT imagine that I have another one like "INumeredEntity" so I will need to create interfaces to all the possibilities

Comment: Very nice solution, I've upvoted your answer because it really solve the problem. 
I've searched a lot and realize that the abstraction that I want to do is actually impossible, so it's a nice solution even allowing 'newbie' developers to use the 'wrong' method at developing time and discovering that it is impossible at run time. 
thank you